# Best Practices for JPA - joining read-only data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join

I am using a JPA model with two classes. The first one is mapping a table with "dynamic" data, the second one is mapping a table with read-only, reference data.

As an example, I have a `Person` entity mapping a Person Table, that contains a @OneToOne reference to the `Civility` entity, which itself maps to the Civility table (2 columns) that only has 3 records in it (Miss, Mrs and Mr).

I wanted to know the best way to write a query on the person entity based on Civility value. For example, what query would I use to get all Person's with civility = Mr?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/  Show what you have tried

Comment: This is a bit off-topic, but `Civility` is called `Salutation` in most databases.  Actually, I've never seen it called anything else.

Answer (score 1):

one way to map reference lookup data is to use the @Enumerated annotation in jpa.  You still have to create enumeration with the lookup values, but that's why it's reference data anyway.

For example, I have a rating code, and its a string/varchar value on table. 
But can use a enumeration to use it:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column
public RatingCode getRating() {
  return rating;
}
public void setRating(RatingCode rating) {
   this.rating = rating;
}
```

and the enumeration is:

```
public enum RatingCode {
    Core, Star
}
```

Use a unit test to try all values, and you know it's a safe way to get reference data.

You can still use HQL to pull out the values, and pass the enumeration as the value:

```
hql = "select r from Rating as r where r.rating = :aEnum"

// and in the call to pass the parameter
qry.setParameter("aEnum", aRatingCode)
```

The enumeration is a field within the Rating entity:

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Rating {

    private Integer rating_Id;

    private RatingCode rating;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column
    public Integer getRating_Id() {
        return rating_Id;
    }
    public void setRating_Id(Integer rating_Id) {
        this.rating_Id = rating_Id;
    }

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column
    public RatingCode getRating() {
        return rating;
    }
    public void setRating(RatingCode rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

}
```

So I have a profile, that requires a Rating, so I lookup a rating via the enumeration and add it to the profile.

```
Profile p = new Profile();
RatingServiceI rs = new RatingService()
Rating r = rs.getRating(RatingCode.Core);
p.setRating(r);
```

Comment: Coool!! i didn't know that such technique exists.Is this way is more efficient and performant comparing to the query sent by "Perception" juste before?

Comment: Yes. it's a great way of hooking the lookup data to the actual code.  If you create a unit test to check these values against the database you are able to identify if these change.  It also keeps the code more sane, as you are able to use the enumeration without fear of it not representing the datamodel.

Comment: Thank you so much for this preconization. Juste one more question, if i have to persist the entity that have a reference to RatingCode's datamodel, the fact that i use an enumeration as data type does not break the link betweene the two tables?

Comment: Nope, it does not break the link.  You can use it as a proper linked lookup.  The enumeration is also useful to help fill values for thinks like drop downs and check boxes, safe in the knowledge the values represent the data.

Comment: So if i recapitulate: Suppose we have a "Movie" class (mapping a movie table). This class contains an attribute typed RatingCode annotated as you describe(@Enumerated). RatingCode is also a table containing two fields (code, value). If i insert a new movie in the database with ratingcode "star", jpa will insert it in the movie table with the right code value of "star" in the database?

Comment: Not quite, the RatingCode is an field within a entity Rating.  I will add to the answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your entity definitions, so you will need to interpret the code in this answer to match up with your actual models. Also, note that querying the entities themselves, in this case, has nothing to do whether the data in the underlying tables is 'read-only' or not:

```
final String queryStr = "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.civility.value = :value";
final TypedQuery<Person> query = entityManager.createQuery(queryStr, Person.class);
query.setParameter("value", "Mr");
List<Person> results = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Hy :) thx for you reponse. I was just wondering if it is the best way, because this is exactly what i did, but i thinked that doing a lookup for the entity civility (a sort of findbyLabel that return the instance C of Civility)before executing the query you described, changing it to ""SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.civility = :c" with c the instance i got from my "findByLabel" method

Comment: You don't need to look up the Civility object first if you just want to do a lookup. There are various ways you can cross-reference it in a JPQL query without actually reading it separately first.

Comment: I see what you mean, but i was just asking about the best pratice to write the query or do the mapping to have the most performant execution time?